# Receiving 403 (rate limited) errors from Google Calendar API

Tags: google-oauth, google-calendar-api, rate-limiting, google-developers-console

We are using the Google Calendar API to keep a sync between our app and events in our users' google calendar.

We have started regularly getting rate limiting errors (403).

However our usage according the APIs and Services page of the google cloud console is well below the stated limits (10,000 queries per minute and 600 per user per minute). We are also using the batch API to send our requests so cannot implement exponential backoff

Anyone got any advice on avoiding these rate limiting errors?

Comment: Do you have a link to the docs where you were able to start calendar syncing? I am in need of doing this as well and can see, add, delete and such. But now I need to start synching with another calendar (or our system) and not finding much documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rate limiting errors with google are basically flood protection you are going to fast.  Dont hold to much stock in what the status shows on the Google developer console the numbers in those graphs are guesstimates at best and they are not Realtime.

The main cause for rate limit is that when you send a request there is no way of know which server your request is going to be run on.  There is also no way of knowing what other requests are being run on the same server.  So your request may run faster or slower than you would expect sometimes which makes it hard to track down exactly what  **10,000 queries per minute and 600 per user per minute** actually is.

10000 requests run on an overloaded server may run in 2 minutes while on a server that is not being overloaded it could be run in 30 seconds meaning the next request you send will blow out the quota.

As there is really no way of avoiding it you you should just ensure that your application is capable of responding to it by sending the request again.  I wrote an article a number of years ago about how i would track my requests locally in my application and then ensured that it kept things at the right speed [flood buster](https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/)

Really as long as your application responds by sending the request again you should be ok.